# Pandas: how to plot a line in a scatter and bring it to the back/front?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have checked to the best of my capabilities but haven't found any `kwds` that allow you to draw a line (such as `y=a-x`) on a `pandas` scatter plot (not necessarily the line of best fit) and bring it to the back (or to the front).

```
#the data frame
ax=df.plot(kind='scatter', x='myX', y='myY',title="Nice title", 
   xlim=[0,100],ylim=[0,100],figsize=(8,5), grid=True,fontsize=10)

#the line
lnsp=range(0,110,10)
line=[100-i for i in lnsp] #line is y=100-x
ax=line_df.plot(kind='line',color='r',ax=ax,legend=False,grid=True,linewidth=3)
```

Is there anything I can use? Or is it just the order in which the two things are drawn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define an axis, and then pass the pandas plot to that axis. You then plot whatever line to that previously defined axis. Here is a solution.

```
np.random.seed(365)  # for repeatable data
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
line = 0.5*np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
x_line = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y})
#You pass the wanted axis to the ax argument
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y',title="Nice title", grid=True,fontsize=10, ax=ax) 
ax.plot(line, x_line, zorder=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to modify the zorder. Here is an option. This will bring line to the back. `ax.plot(line, x_line, zorder=-1, color="red")`.